How to Calculate Equivalent Thickness from Aluminum 6061 to Stainless Steel AISI 304
I'm working on a project that involves switching materials from aluminum 6061 to stainless steel AISI 304. I need to calculate the equivalent thickness to ensure similar structural performance, given the differences in mechanical properties between these materials.
I understand that factors such as tensile strength, modulus of elasticity, and density play a crucial role. Can someone provide guidance or a formula for determining the equivalent thickness when making this material switch?
Any insights or references to engineering standards would be greatly appreciated.

This cannot be answered in general terms, since depending on geometry, you need different formulas for different parts. There can also be difference in influence of operating conditions on the same geometry made from different materials, so you may also need to consider physical properties. Could you provide more details about the geometry and operating conditions?

Hi Tomas !, thank u to responding to my post, yes i could provide you more details.
I have 1 bracket which is a 5 mm thick aluminium plate, in this bracket 4 ignition coils are mounted on this plate, what the plate does is to support weight, I want to know how thick this same plate should be if it is made of stainless steel.

It is better to update the question with new details, so that people don't have to look for them in discussion. Your plate might primarily be loaded by bending, where the extreme bending stress is $\sigma_b = \frac{6M}{w\cdot t^2}$ ($M$ is bending moment, $t$ is thickness, $w$ is width) and you need to limit this stress using allowable stress. The allowable stress is usually based on yield strength and/or ultimate tensile strength with appropriate safety factors. From this, if lets say the new material is 2x stronger, the required thickness would be $1/\sqrt{2}$ times the original thickness.
